# How to select rows in swt table

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

I am trying to create a UI using SWT in eclipse. I have a table with multiple rows and two buttons Start and Next.When I click on Start, the first row is supposed to get selected. When I click Next, the next row has to be selected. And when a row is selected I have to read the corresponding row data. 
I tried using

```java
tableViewer.getTable().setFocus();
tableViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(tableViewer.getElementAt(0)),true);
```

But no row is getting selected.

I also tried with `table.getSelection(0);`
And now each row is selected but with grey colour.As a result the row selection is not invoking `table.addListener()`.

Please help me with this. I am new to this topic.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `setSelection` should work. I think you should show us more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed

```
 tableViewer.refresh ();
```

before doing setSelection